# Ignoring a line beginning with a '#' in command prompt

Tags: c++

I am writing a code which requires me to ignore comment lines (i.e, lines beginning with a # sign) till the end of the line. I'm using linux to code in c++. For e.g: in case of adding two numbers.

```
xxx@ubuntu:~ $ ./add
Enter the two numbers to be added
1 #this is the first number
2 #this is the second number
result: 3
```

So the comment line can be anywhere. It just has to ignore the entire line and take the next value as input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a,b;


cout<< "Enter the two numbers to be added:\n";
while(cin >>a >>b)
{
if (a == '#'|| b == '#')
continue;
cout << "Result: "<<a+b;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted?  Otherwise we have to make assumptions about your code.

Comment: im very new to this, i donot know how to add code here.. But here is it..

Comment: Click on --> [edit]   :)

Comment: `cin >>a >>b` is not a good idea if the input isn't an `int`.  `a` and `b` can only hold integers, according to your design.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have shown, I think this might be what you want.

```
int main()
{
    string comment;
    int nr1,nr2;
    // Read the first number. It should be the first one always. No comment before number!
    cin >> nr1;            

    // See if we can read the second number Successfully. Which means it is an integer.
    if(cin >> nr2) {
    } 
    // Otherwise clear cin and read the rest of the comment line                        
    else {
        cin.clear();           
        getline(cin,comment);
        // Now read the second number from the second line
        cin >> nr2;           
    }
    // Read the rest of second the line.
    getline(cin,comment);   

    cout << "result: " << nr1 + nr2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @anusha you want to handle this too? `1 2` in one line?

Comment: It does work. But when it comes to comment line it should work irrespective of wherever it is right.. Even in the first line. Im working on that now...

Answer (score 0):

Will any number of numbers based on the value you give `reqd`.
Will also work if the first character in a line itself is `#` - will ask again for that line. Will also read another line if there is no number before the `#.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const int reqd = 2;
    string sno[reqd];
    int no[reqd];
    int got = 0;
    size_t pos;
    istringstream is;

    cout<< "Enter "<<reqd<<" numbers to be added:\n";
    while(got < reqd)
    {
        getline(cin, sno[got]);
        if((pos = sno[got].find('#')) && isdigit(sno[got][0]))
        {
            is.str(sno[got]);
            is>>no[got];
            ++got;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < reqd; ++i)
        sum+=no[i];

    cout<<"Result : "<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, i think it is returning the wrong result. It does skip the comment line though.. At the first line as well..

Comment: @anusha - it doesn't ` C:\tmp>a
Enter 2 numbers to be added:
1 #this is the first number
2 #this is the second number
Result : 3`

Comment: But if there are no comment lines it gives a different answer.

Comment: @anusha - Ok - I didn't realize there could be 2 numbers on the same line. My program assumes each line contains only 1 number. Will fix it later to take more than one number on the same line.

Comment: so this # sign is to be considered as a comment line. It can be anywhere in the command prompt.